# Create condition that searches between two different WHEREs in the table

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm making a little game where robots fight each other. The robots have a table in the database where their match scores are recorded. Each robot has its own home island where it can face opponents. The opponents will have their own island. Each robot has its own island. The question is simple enough, but it could lead to confusion, so I briefly explain step by step:

**EXPLANATION**

**1.** I select the name of a particular robot from the combobox

```
if robot_her_island:
select_robot_on_her_island = select_war.split('-')[0]
```

**2.** Using `Last_War_on_any_island` I search for the last war of the selected robot. I look for either the war that took place on your own island or on the island of your opponents. I only select the last war

```
#Last War on ANY island
cursor.execute("SELECT robot_on_her_island, robot_on_island_away, points_war_home, points_war_away FROM War WHERE robot_on_her_island =? OR robot_on_island_away=? LIMIT 1", [select_robot_on_her_island, select_robot_on_her_island])
Last_War_on_any_island = cursor.fetchall()[0]
```

**3.** I create two separate cursor.execute: one for when a robot fights on its own island and another when a robot fights on an island not its own. How come? Because the problem might seem solved like this in point 2, but it's okay only when the war is between `robot_on_her_island` VS `robot_on_island_away` (the two data in the database) and then the corresponding points are points_war_home and points_war_away. But when the war is backwards, i.e. `robot_on_island_away` VS `robot_on_her_island`, then I should also reverse `points_war_away`-`points_war_home`, because I'm trying to get information about a certain robot (selected in the initial combo box).

Consequently, to solve this, I thought about creating two separate cursor.execute, one for when a robot is fighting on its own island (`Last_War_on_her_island`) and another when a robot is fighting off on an island not its own (`Last_War_on_island_away`). This way I can also swap points_war_home and points_war_away (on the contrary, by reversing the order)

I give an example of point 3:

MAZINGER VS GOLDRAKE
robot_on_her_island VS robot_on_island_away = points_war_home, points_war_away (Mazinger, Goldrake = 2-1)

GOLDRAKE VS MAZINGER
robot_on_her_island VS robot_on_island_away = points_war_away, points_war_home (Goldrake-Mazinger = 3-2) #invert points

```
#Last War in robot home island
cursor.execute("SELECT points_war_home, points_war_away FROM War WHERE robot_on_her_island =? LIMIT 1", [select_robot_on_her_island])
Last_War_on_her_island = cursor.fetchall()[0]

#Last War in robot away island (robot island opponents)
cursor.execute("SELECT points_war_away, points_war_home FROM War WHERE robot_on_island_away =? LIMIT 1", [select_robot_on_her_island])
Last_War_on_island_away= cursor.fetchall()[0]
```

Good! Now I have the last robot_on_her_island war, and the last robot rival robot_on_island_away war. Perfect, but the problem is right here!

**QUESTION**

How do I know if the last robot war that I initially selected from combobox was carried out on its own island or on that of some other robot?

The answer is the cursor.execute I used above called `Last_War_on_any_island`, but I don't know how to put the code together. Let me explain: having `Last_War_on_any_island` which serves to find out what was the last general war of the robot that I selected with the combobox, then using `Last_War_on_any_island` I would like to be able to get `Last_War_on_her_island` or `Last_War_on_island_away`

**FOR EXAMPLE I WANT TO GET THIS:**

[image]

For example, if I choose Daitarn in the combobox, the last war of Daitarn will be sought, which is the one in id 2 (Jeeg-Daitarn). Then Last_War_on_island_away will be printed. While if I had chosen Mazinger in the combobox, Mazinger's last war would have been in id 1 (Mazinger-Goldrake) and therefore Last_War_on_her_island would have been printed. IMPORTANT: When I say "last" I refer to the last time the robot NAME is displayed in the tab (indifferently from Home or Away, or ID), but only the last time the name is present

**CODE COMPLETE**

```
    if robot_her_island:
    
    robot_her_island = select_war.split('-')[0]      
    
    #Last War on ANY island
    cursor.execute("SELECT robot_on_her_island, robot_on_island_away, points_war_home, points_war_away FROM War WHERE robot_on_her_island =? OR robot_on_island_away=? LIMIT 1", [select_robot_on_her_island, select_robot_on_her_island])
    Last_War_on_any_island = cursor.fetchall()[0]
    
    #Last War in robot home island
    cursor.execute("SELECT points_war_home, points_war_away FROM War WHERE robot_on_her_island =? LIMIT 1", [select_robot_on_her_island])
    Last_War_on_her_island = cursor.fetchall()[0]
    
    #Last War in robot away island (robot island opponents)
    cursor.execute("SELECT points_war_away, points_war_home FROM War WHERE robot_on_island_away =? LIMIT 1", [select_robot_on_her_island])
    Last_War_on_island_away= cursor.fetchall()[0]

    #THE PROBLEM IS HERE
    if Last_War_on_any_island is Last_War_on_her_island:
        print(Last_War_on_her_island)
    else
        print(Last_War_on_island_away)
```

Comment: You keep saying "the last record", but SQL records are not ordered.  Unless you use an `ORDER BY` clause, you are getting a record at random.

Comment: You don't show us where you got `last_company_value`, but if that is one records, then `[4]` is selecting the 5th field, and you only have two fields.

Comment: @TimRoberts I don't have to sort the records. The order of the records is already correct at present. Using ORDER BY breaks everything. I use the last of the records thanks to LIMIT. I've done some tests and LIMIT is fine for my case. Last_company_value I got it thanks to cursor.execute. Last_company_value is shown at the beginning of the question

Comment: @TimRoberts Can you help me please?

Comment: There's no inherent order in SQL tables. If "the order of records is already correct at present", it's just by accident, you shouldn't rely on it. You should have something in the table that specifies the order you want.

Comment: @Barmar No, the correct order is not just by chance. I have created algorithms to sort the records according to some methods. I don't think it's a record order problem, because with WHERE company1 =? OR company2 =? LIMIT 1 I can do what I need perfectly. What I fail to do is create the condition based on whether the result of Last_company_value is with company1 and company2. Can you help me please?

Comment: What do you mean by "created algorithms to sort the records"? How did you make SQLIte keep the rows in that order?

Comment: Are you assuming that the default order will be the order that the rows were inserted into the table?

Comment: @Barmar Maybe I didn't understand what you are saying. But if I understand, then the answer is yes

Comment: I don't think that's guaranteed. Use an AUTO_INCREMENT ID field, and order by that.

Comment: SQL RECORDS ARE NOT ORDERED.  That is a fact.  They sometimes seem to be listed in creation order, but that is an accident.  If the database decides to clean up stale data, they might appear in a new order.  YOU MUST USE `ORDER BY` TO GET THE ORDER YOU WANT.  This is not negotiable.

Comment: Are you showing the wars in reverse order? Why is ID 2 the last for Daiturn, not ID 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the test for whether it's home or away in the query itself.

```
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN robot_on_her_island = ? THEN 'Last_War_on_her_island'
             ELSE 'Last_War_on_island_away'
        END AS which_island,
        points_war_home, points_war_away
    FROM war
    WHERE ? IN (robot_on_her_island, robot_on_island_away)
    LIMIT 1""",
    (select_robot_on_her_island, select_robot_on_her_island))
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row:
    which_island, points_home, points_away = row
    if which_island == 'Last_War_on_her_island':
        print(which_island, points_home, points_away)
    else:
        # Swap the points when won on the away island
        print(which_island, points_away, points_home)
```

BTW, if you just want one row, use `fetchone()` rather than `fetchall()[0]`.

Comment: What do Last_company_value [0] and [1] correspond to?

Comment: The first two columns in the row that was fetched, which are `company1` and `company2`.

Comment: There is something wrong with your code. I always get "Last company is company2". I've done dozens of tests. I also tried when I was 100% sure that I should receive "Last company is company1". Maybe it doesn't work because combo_company is always present in both Last_company_value [0] and [1]. I should only use company1 and company2 which use WHERE company1 =? OR company2 =? LIMIT 1. Do you have any other solution? I've been trying to solve it for days, but I can't. Thanks

Comment: `condition1 OR condition2` is true if either or both conditions are true.

Comment: Use `XOR` if you only want a row where one of the companies matches, but not both.

Comment: But I don't get what I want from the press. There is something wrong. If I try to print only Last_Company_in_Company1 and Last_Company_in_Company2 (they are above in my question) I get what I want.The problem is that only one of those two I have to print, based on Last_company_value which takes the last company of company1 or company2. While Last_Company_in_Company1 and Last_Company_in_Company2 only print them separately,but I don't know which one is really the last one (which I discover thanks to Last_company_value).Having said that, do you have any other solution to help me? (PART 1)

Comment: (PART 2) About XOR, can you show me how to use it? I've never used it. Thank you

Comment: `WHERE company1 = ? XOR company2 = ?`

Comment: I get sqlite3.OperationalError: near "XOR": syntax error

Comment: Oops, I was thinking or MySQL

Comment: Use `WHERE (company1 = ?) != (company2 = ?)`

Comment: Now,after some tests,i always get Not found in company1 or company2. Maybe! = Is not useful in my case.However, there is something wrong with your code. I really appreciate your help,but there is something wrong with the logic of the code. The code is obviously correct,but that's not what I was looking for.Basically Last_company_value checks which is the last company in the database.I want to print Last_Company_in_Company1 or Last_Company_in_Company2,depending on whether the last company was in company1 or 2 in the database.Do you have any other solution? I don't really know how to fix

Comment: Please edit the question. Show sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Okay thanks. I edited the question especially for you. I wrote my real help case. It's the same one I asked for earlier, but I simplified it to make it shorter to read and easier. Do not be frightened by the length of the question, because it is very simple, but I am the one who stretched my explanation. can you help me? Thank you

Comment: Since I assume a robot can never fight itself, I don't think there's any need for XOR here. The robot you're looking for will only be in one column or the other, not both in the same row.

Comment: Thanks so much. Now I'm not home, later (in a few hours) I'll try and I'll let you know. Thank you

Comment: Your answer is correct and I thank you,but it is not what I was looking for.I didn't want to get the result by searching directly in print.I see you get the result via {which_island} and {points [which_island]} which are inside your print.I want to use print only to print Last_War_on_her_island or Last_War_on_island_away. I would like to print these two,using an IF and an ELSE (as in my question code), not searching for these directly in print. You understood what I was looking for,but as per the question I wanted to get it in another way. Can you show me a second way please? thank you

Comment: You can print whatever you want once you have the result.

Comment: I updated the answer to print what you want.

Comment: The data inside Last_War_on_her_island or Last_War_on_island_away is not recovered. The text inside THEN is printed exactly.

Comment: I don't understand, what data?

Comment: Do you need to know the name of the opponent?

Comment: I would like to print the whole line Last_War_on_her_island = cursor.fetchall () [0] or the whole line Last_War_on_island_away = cursor.fetchall () [0]. If you go up and read my question, the data is written inside the relative cursor.execute of both. In Last_War_on_her_island I would like to print SELECT points_war_home, points_war_away FROM War WHERE robot_on_her_island =? LIMIT 1 ", while in Last_War_on_island_away (" SELECT points_war_away, points_war_home FROM War WHERE robot_on_island_away =? LIMIT 1 ". Nothing is printed with your update

Comment: Surely all the answers I've given have shown you all the general principles, you should be able to figure this out on your own.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240519/discussion-between-barmar-and-bobby).

Comment: Everything seems OK. All perfect. Thank you. Voted and accepted response as a solution. If you have any questions about anything about your code, can I leave a comment in the future?