# Function with condition does not return results

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return

Why can't I print the condition results of this function? Why can't I return the various results of this function? I can't even print them. What am I doing wrong? How to fix?

I don't receive errors, but nothing is printed, as if the function were invisible. I also tried to call it back with island(), but it doesn't print

```
def island():

    select_robot_on_her_island = select_war.split('-')[0]      
    
    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN robot_on_her_island = ? THEN 'Last_War_on_her_island'
                 ELSE 'Last_War_on_island_away'
            END AS which_island,
            points_war_home, points_war_away
        FROM war
        WHERE ? IN (robot_on_her_island, robot_on_island_away)
        LIMIT 1""",
        (select_robot_on_her_island, select_robot_on_her_island))
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    if row:
        which_island, points_home, points_away = row
        if which_island == 'Last_War_on_her_island':
            return points_home_left = points_home
            return points_away_left = points_away
            return print("aaaa", which_island, points_home, points_away)
        else:
            # Swap the points when won on the away island
            return points_away_right = points_away
            return points_home_right = points_home
            return print("bbbb", which_island, points_away, points_home)
```

Comment: As soon as you hit a `return` statement, the function ends, and the other `return` statements won't execute.  What are you trying to do here?  Your `return` statements are assignments.  What do you expect the function to return?

Comment: This cannot be your code.  This gets a syntax error for those return statements with assignments.  Please show us the code you are really using.

Comment: @TimRoberts Based on whether the condition is false or true, I would like 2 things to be returned: points_home_left = points_home and points_away_left = points_away, and then I would like to print them just for testing. So I would like to get 2 things for True or 2 things for False

Comment: think about what you are trying to accomplish here.  If the `which_island' == 'Last_War...'` condition is true, do you want to return points_home_left and points_away_left?  If so, just do `return points_home_left, points_away_left`. Also if you want to print something, do it before the return, or after these values are returned in the place that called the function.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  You can return `points_home`, but you cannot return `points_home_left = points_home`.

Comment: @TimRoberts This is my code. It works fine for me. This code was suggested to me in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70491840/create-condition-that-searches-between-two-different-wheres-in-the-table

Comment: @Bobby - Your code is not valid python syntax and is different from the code you referenced.

Comment: @ekrall I used points_home_left = points_home and not points_home, because points_home_left I would like to use later or in the future for other reasons, so I thought about creating it inside the function. Is there no way to get points_home_left = points_home to return?

Comment: why can't you just do `points home_left = points_home`; `points_away_left = points_away`; `return points_home_left, points_away_left` as three separate lines?  Although I'm not sure I see the reason why you need to assign new variables instead of just returning `points_home` and `points_away`, you are closer to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after.  You can return two things from a function, but that has to be done on one statement.

```
def island():

    select_robot_on_her_island = select_war.split('-')[0]      
    
    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN robot_on_her_island = ? THEN 'Last_War_on_her_island'
                 ELSE 'Last_War_on_island_away'
            END AS which_island,
            points_war_home, points_war_away
        FROM war
        WHERE ? IN (robot_on_her_island, robot_on_island_away)
        LIMIT 1""",
        (select_robot_on_her_island, select_robot_on_her_island))
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    if row:
        which_island, points_home, points_away = row
        print("aaaa", which_island, points_home, points_away)
        if which_island == 'Last_War_on_her_island':
            return points_home, points_away
        else:
            return points_away, points_home
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: I used points_home_left = points_home and not points_home, because points_home_left I would like to use later or in the future for other reasons, so I thought about creating it inside the function. Is there no way to get points_home_left = points_home to return?

Comment: No.  Now, whoever is calling `island()` can certainly store the return values whereever it wants.  It is possible to set global variables within a function, but it's almost always a bad idea.  Just have the function return "facts", and let the caller decide what to do with them.  Maybe you need to return the home/away status, as in `return "home", points_home, points_away` and `return "away", points_home, points_away`.

Comment: You can use the code Tim posted and when you call the function use `home_left, home_right = island()` or any other names you may want. Return doesn't pass variable names to the caler, only the values of the variables are returned from a function.

Answer (score 0):

1. The first return that gets executed breaks out of the function, which means no return statements following it will be executed. But you can pass multiple values out of a function using a tuple:

   ```
   def my_func():
       return "one", "two"
   a, b = my_func()
   ```
2. Print displays things, it doesn't return anything, so don't use `return print()`